# Applying multiple aggregation functions over geopandas

Tags: python-3.x, aggregation, geopandas

I am facing serious difficulties in applying multiple aggregation functions over the dissolve function in a geopandas geodataframe.

Though the operation does work, the resultant geodataframe columns get structured as single tuples. If it were structured in a pandas multiIndex.from_tuples structure, there would be no problem with my analysis. Since it is only a a sequence of Tuples, I can't properly operate the geodataframe after the aggregation operation.

Here is a snipped code so to present my point.

The given GeoDataFrame contains several columns as follows:

```
['GEOCODE_4', 'Datetime', 'geometry', 'Precipitacao_1000m', 'COD_UF','COD_MUNIC', 'POP', 'POP_Esperada', 'HAV', 'Incidencia','Incidencia_10_3e', 'Year']
```

In my study case, I am trying to evaluate the aggregated "mean" and "sum" of those variables above. For that matter, I use the dissolve function from the geodataframe as presented below.

```
# Initial geodataframe (refered as GDF):

GDF_temporal_reduced = GDF.dissolve(by='GEOCODE_4', aggfunc=['sum', 'mean'])
```

After the dissolve function is applied, I end up with a Geodataframe whose columns are structured as Tuples:

```
# GDF_temporal_reduced.columns 

    # returns the following index:

['geometry',  
('Precipitacao_1000m', 'sum'),     ('Precipitacao_1000m', 'mean'),
('COD_UF', 'sum'),                 ('COD_UF', 'mean'),
('COD_MUNIC', 'sum'),              ('COD_MUNIC', 'mean'),
('POP', 'sum'),                    ('POP', 'mean'),
('POP_Esperada', 'sum'),           ('POP_Esperada', 'mean'),  
('HAV', 'sum'),                    ('HAV', 'mean'),
('Incidencia', 'sum'),             ('Incidencia', 'mean'),
('Incidencia_10_3e', 'sum'),       ('Incidencia_10_3e', 'mean'),
('Year', 'sum'),                   ('Year', 'mean')]
```

Here is the look of my GDF:

[image: GDF after reduction]

Once these columns are now in Tuple, and not precisely in Multiindex form, I can not properly filter them after the whole operation.

Does anyone know a way such as to get a reduced GDF as below?

[image: Desired reduced GDF]

I thank you for your time,

sincerely yours,

Philipe Leal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples should work with your column structure, the problem is the non-tuple geometry column. I guess there is a way of including the geometry column when manually building the multiindex, but for simplicity I just dropped it. Just reattach the geometry column if you still need it.

```
df = df.drop('geometry', axis=1)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns)
df = df.swaplevel(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A better idea than dissolve is to first use groupby function in pandas, and then assemble the pandas
dataframework into a new geopandas dataframework. The good side of doing this is
you can specify different aggregation methods for different columns. let's say Sum
for Pop and Mean for Prep

```
GDF_merged = gpd.GeoDataFrame(GDF.groupby('GEOCODE_4').agg({'geometry':'first', 
                                                           'Pop': "sum", 
                                                           'Prep':'mean' }).reset_index(),
                                                           geometry="geometry",
                                                           crs = GDF.crs
                              )
```